# How to test with Jest whether action created by action creator (and not passed as prop) fires?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I try to test whether a given action is really fired in a component. It could be easy if the callback with action was delivered as a prop, but it's not clear for me how to do it in my case. Here is the component:

```
export const Modal = (props: appendProps): JSX.Element => {
    const { items, activeScope } = props;
    const primary = items[0] === activeScope;
    const { closeInput, appendItem } = useDispatchAction();
{...}
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      size="large"
      className="modal-content__button"
      color="secondary"
      onClick={() => {
           closeInput();
      }}
      >
       Zamknij
   </Button>
```

useDispatchAction is below:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { actionCreators } from '../redux';

const useDispatchAction = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
};

export default useDispatchAction;
```

And test itself below

```
describe('Test button actions', () => {
    const closeInput = jest.fn();
    jest.mock('../../src/hooks/useDispatchAction', () => ({closeInput}));

    beforeEach(() => {
        render(<Modal />);
    });
    afterEach(() => cleanup());
    test('component fires closeInput', () => {
        const closeButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Zamknij' });
        expect(closeButton).toBeInTheDocument();
        userEvent.click(closeButton);
        expect(closeInput).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

but this keep telling me that function has been called 0 times and not 1 at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally works is:

```
const actions = {
    closeInput: jest.fn(),
    appendItem: jest.fn(),
};

jest.mock('../../src/hooks/useDispatchAction', () => () => actions);

describe('Given Modal component', () => {
    describe('when "Zamknij" button is clicked', () => {
        it('should call closeInput function', async () => {
            actions.closeInput.mockClear();

            const { findByText } = render(<Modal />);
            const closeButton = await findByText('Zamknij');

            fireEvent.click(closeButton);

            expect(actions.closeInput).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `jest.mock`, you get a function that returns `undefined` by default. So, if `useDispatchAction` returns `undefined`, you can't go `const { closeInput, appendItem } = useDispatchAction();`, because you cannot destructure from `undefined`.

However, you can [supply a second argument](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to `jest.mock`:

```js
const closeInput = jest.fn()
jest.mock('../../src/hooks/useDispatchAction', () => ({ closeInput }))
```

Now you've mocked `useDispatchAction` to return something that looks more like your original function, except that the action returns something you can assert was called.

You can test it like this:

`expect(closeInput).toHaveBeenCalled()`

I think this should work, but I haven't tested this particular code.

Comment: It is definitely better, no errors now, but also it does not notice any calls.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I wonder if you might need make this asynchronous. Can you try importing `waitFor`, make the function you pass to `test` async, and wrap your expect like this: `await waitFor(() => expect(closeInput).toBeCalled())`